# Can I use Gls() or glmer() to predict binary outcomes with restricted cubic splines predictors?

Tags: lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, glmm, splines, rms

I'm new to `rms`, as I read the rms book and notes, I saw that the `Gls()` function could be used to make a longitudinal growth curve.

Now I'm dealing with some mulitlevel data which has some personal level 1 variables and a study sites level 2 variable. And my outcome is a binary variable.

To my understanding, a 2-level model could be applied to the `Gls()` function.
However, for a binary outcome, we usally use logistic regression which in the `rms` package is the `lmr()` function.

I know I should use a generalized linear multilevel model `glmm`. AND I also learned `lme4` package contains the `glmer()` function for that.

But I also want to use restricted cubic splines to some variables. `rcs()` function is well doing in the `rms` package.

So, the question is could I use `Gls()` for a binary outcome. Or could I just simply put the `rcs()` part in the formula in a `glmer()` function?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use restricted cubic splines with a multilevel structure for logistic regression in mgcv, or for more complicated structures gamm4.